# Prove little-O from first principles

Tags: math, little-o

Prove that f(n) = 2010n^2 + 1388n belongs to o(n^3)

[Little-O Definition](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/littleOnotation.html)

My work so far:
This must be true: for ALL constats c>0, there exists a constant n0>0 such that 
0<=2010n^2 + 1388n<=cn^3 for all n>n0

By simplifying we get:
c>= 2010/n + 1388/n^2

Not sure what to do next to find n0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an easier time with an [equivalent definition of little-o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation): we say that f = o(g) if

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> f(n) / g(n) = 0

In your case, this means that you'd prove that

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (2010n<sup>2</sup> + 1388n) / n<sup>3</sup> = 0

To see this, note that

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (2010n<sup>2</sup> + 1388n) / n<sup>3</sup>
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (2010n<sup>2</sup> / n<sup>3</sup>) + (1388n) / n<sup>3</sup>
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (2010 / n) + (1388 / n<sup>2</sup>)
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (2010 / n) + lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (1388 / n<sup>2</sup>)
>
> = 0 + 0
>
> = 0

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was an alternate definition.